# Linux jTDS driver fails login to MS SQL Server after NTLM v2 required by policy

Tags: sql-server, linux, jtds

I have an application which uses the jTDS JDBC driver to access Microsoft SQL Server databases and slurp the data into Oracle databases. After the domain policies were changed to require NTLM version 2 for authentication, logins began to fail with the error message

> java.sql.SQLException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

I verified with the Windows domain admins that the password for the account used is correct and the account is neither locked nor expired. Based on other posts I added the "useNTLMv2=true" parameter to the end of the JDBC URL and expanded the domain parameter to a fully-qualified domain name without success. I checked the jTDS version and found it to be 1.2 (even though Maven says it should be 1.3.1).

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, jTDS 1.2 does not support NTLM v2. I had to upgrade to jTDS 1.3.1 in the classpath directory to add this support, and the application is once more successfully authenticating to SQL Server databases.